# Determine whether function continuous or not.

Tags: functions

\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
3x-1&\text{if }x<1\\
4&\text{if }x=1\\
2x&\text{if }x>1
\end{cases}
,~~ c=1\end{equation}

Is this function continuous at $x=c$?

Comment: For a function to be continuous at $c$, $f(c)$ needs to have a finite value (it does). As well you need the right and left limits of $f(x)$ to agree at $x=c$. As an example, the right limit of $2x$ gives you $2c$. Does this agree with $f(c)$?

Comment: @Diaga AoS don't feel bad for someone who unpardonable downvoted. Continuity is one of the most important notions of math and physics and it takes time to get acquainted with it.

Comment: As long as i can ask questions and get answers , i won't care about votes. ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for $f$ to be continuous at $1$, we need to see if
$$\lim_{x\to 1}f(x) \quad\text{and}\quad f(1)$$
both exist and are equal.

To do so, compute the limit from the left, the limit from the right, and $f(1)$. If
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x) = f(1) = \lim_{x\to1^+}f(x),
$$
then $f$ is continuous at $1$. If one of the equalities doesn't hold, then $f$ is not continuous at $1$.

I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: Isn't it $\lim\limits_{x \to c} = f(c)$? I mean right and left limits determine if limit exists and then it is seen that if that limit is equal to the given function. Since , $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} = 4 , f(x)$ should be continuous. Edited.

Comment: @DiagaAoS Do you mean $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = f(c)$? If so, that's correct. In my answer, I just used $1$ instead of $c$ because we are given directly that $c=1$. However, in order to check if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$, we will need to check if the right and left limits are equal to $f(c)$. That's why I split it up in my answer. How do you get $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=4$? That's not correct.

Comment: I understand what you wrote . What I mean if $ f(x) = a $ isn't it generally $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) = a?$ So, $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(1) = 4.$ for this case.

Comment: @DiagaAoS I think you meant to write if $f(c)=a$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=a$? That's not true! In fact, that's precisely what it means for $f$ to be continuous at $c$ - which is what we are supposed to check. The limit $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ is about the behavior of $f$ near $c$, but not at $c$. Knowing the value of $f(c)$ tells us nothing about the limit. The limit could exist when $f$ isn't defined at $c$, or it could be that $f(c)=0$ but the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thankyou . That clears up a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

Continuous means that the function's graph **should atleast visually look continuous.**

### Try plotting it's graph around $x=1$.

**Can you solve it now?**

**Tip**

Consider using MathJax next time. It takes only a few seconds.

Comment: Yes , I use it but i don't know how to write functions like that. I haven't learnt graphs :/

Comment: Okay, then ideally you should at least have some idea of that before exploring limits. You will be blind in one eye if you haven't done functions properly.

Comment: Thankyou  , I'll look up on graphs on net. Actually , we aren't taught graphs since they don't give questions about graphs on board examinations.